Transferring of the Impurity
I once had pre-ejaculation on my hand, and I did not wash it. However I went ahead and I sat and touched everywhere on the carpet.
With this being said, I don’t know if the impurity transferred or not because, my hand wasn’t neither wet or dry. It was more to like a moist matter. HOWEVER my hand was 100% not wet to a point where if I touch the carpet or a think peice of cloth it will soak it.
Due to this; I now feel there is impurity on my carpet, and I cannot make wudu because I keep thinking if I step on the impurity with wet/moist feet, it will transfer to me and I when I step on my wudu mat then this will become impure aswell because my feet were wet.
Can someone please give me some insights on this? Jazak Allahu Khairan

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please check the following similar question How to purify a carpet if I don't remember where the impurity is.

Asalam Alikum!
Brother do not stop praying!
I believe that if you did get it on the carpet just bring a little bit of water on it.
But do not let that stop your prayers! Your journey to jannah al firdaus 
And do not do that again because it's not halal brother, i understand its an addiction I had something similar too before but i quit and I pray everyday Allahamdullah yes I make mistakes but I repent because allah is all forgiving all loving 
And make dua for it to stop inshallah
1.Repent for the past
2.promise Allah you wont do it again
3.Stop it completely
If you end up doing it again then repent again and never ever give up.
I believe in you brother
And just do your best to clean the carpet and in the meantime pray somewhere else although still facing the qibla
And don't be so obsessive with everything like be calm chill Islam is a blessing not a punishment 
But never forget the repentance it is our gateway to jannah inshallah

I will try to clean my carpet, however I’m unsure if the impurity transferred or not, since my hands were moist. What do I do in this case?
